# Moo Tools JS lint

Tags: ubuntu, mootools, debian, package, jslint

I am looking for instructions on setting up JS lint to work with moo tools from Debian Ubuntu command line.
Is there a package for this or instructions that some one can $point me at. If there where instructions I would be happy to make the package!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for this functionality can be found here. It uses NODE JS to run lint from the command line.

https://github.com/as-jpolo/node-lint

I also found this tutorial that proved to be useful not only helping me set up cmd line lint but letting me run it on the fly in VIM is super useful.

http://technotales.wordpress.com/2011/05/21/node-jslint-and-vim/

One thing that I did not get working yet is configure Lint to parse Mootools with out throwing warnings that are expected. When I do figure out how to start to configure Lint I will make sure I post that to.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with a java dependency, [jslint4java](http://code.google.com/p/jslint4java/) makes this easy:

```
java -jar jslint4java.jar myproject/*.js
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the jslint4java wrapper.